# Get data with db with lambda expression and coalesce

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, lambda

I have a question about coalesce and lambda expression. I'm reading from a SQLite database some records but not always there are some of them. For example

```
return db.GetItems<Appointment>().Where(l => l.AppointmentId == appointmentId).First();
```

If there are no appointment I receive an error

> Sequence contains no elements

I agree. Then I tried to change the expression

```
return db.GetItems<Appointment>()?.Where(l => l.AppointmentId == appointmentId)?.First();
```

I thought with first `?` if there are no appointment the function return `null`. I inserted the second `?` for the same reason if the `where` are no appointment.

Then my question is: what did I wrong? Is it possible to do that?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the sequence is empty when you call `First`, not that it is `null`.  What you want is `FirstOrDefault` which will result in the default value (in this case `null`) when the sequence it is called on is empty.

```
return db.GetItems<Appointment>()
    .Where(l => l.AppointmentId == appointmentId)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

You also don't need the null conditional operator after `GetItems` as it should not return `null`, an empty sequence maybe, but not `null`.

Comment: You're right! I don't know why I didn't use it. I'm using this code in another part of my project... I'm getting old :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `First`. It returns default value if the sequence contains **no** elements. And also you don't need the null conditional operator.

```
return db.GetItems<Appointment>()
         .Where(l => l.AppointmentId == appointmentId)
         .FirstOrDefault();
```